# Can we define custom wrapper classes for primitive types which support auto-boxing & auto-unboxing?

Tags: java

I know that Java provides predefined wrapper classes of primitive data types and support auto-boxing & auto-unboxing when working with objects created by these classes. Yet, I cannot find out if Java really allows us to define custom wrapper classes like those predefined ones and provide some implementations to the compiler to support auto-boxing & auto-unboxing?

```java
Integer a = 9;
Integer b = a + 1;
// here, a is an object and auto-unboxed to make the + works,
// then the result is auto-boxed back into an Integer wrapper
// before the assignment to b.
```

Is it possible to define a custom wrapper class like Integer with custom constrains and support auto-boxing and auto-unboxing?

```java
class Age
extends Number {
   public static final int MIN_VALUE = 0;
   public static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
   // ...
}

Age before = 9;
Age after = before + 100;
// Out Range Exception
// after = 9 + 100 is greater than Age.MAX_VALUE
```

Comment: No. Auto-boxing is handled by the compiler specifically for the built-in wrappers and can't be extended with user-defined types.